# Django 'change' can not find existing object

Tags: python, django

Currentli my django project still using Sqlite as db.
I have a model named 'Monitoring'.

```
class Monitoring(models.Model):
    tebar=models.ForeignKey(Tebar,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='monitoring',)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name=("Tanggal"),
        auto_now_add=True, null=True,
        editable=False,)
    prevmon=models.ForeignKey('self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='nextmon',
        editable=False,
        blank=True, null=True)
    dead = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Jml. Mati', default=0,
        null=True)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Bahan,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='monitoringfood',
        verbose_name='Pakan',
        blank=True, null=True)
    foodqty=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0,
        verbose_name='Berat Pakan',)
    suplemen=models.ForeignKey(Bahan,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='monitoringsupl',
        verbose_name='Suplemen',
        blank=True, null=True)
    suplqty=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=0,
        verbose_name='juml.Supl.',)
    feedcost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,
        default=0.0,
        blank=True, null=True)
    ph = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,
        blank=True, null=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2,
        verbose_name='gram/ekor', default=0.0,
        null=True)
    wateradd= models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Tambah Air',
        null=True, blank=True,
        help_text='Penambahan Tinggi Air dalam Cm')

    class Meta :
        verbose_name_plural='7. Perlakuan'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}; {}'.format(self.tebar, self.date_created)
```

I add one record, get success.
I try to change the record, the web page go to the /admin
and  under the site name line I got msg:

```
    Monitoring with ID “6” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted?
```

I try to access the db via django console, and that record is there.

```
>>> from catatkolam.models import *
>>> Monitoring.objects.get(id=6)
<Monitoring: kolam 1@2021-05-02; 2021-05-06 07:19:53.288664+00:00>
>>> Monitoring.objects.get(id='6')
<Monitoring: kolam 1@2021-05-02; 2021-05-06 07:19:53.288664+00:00>
>>>
```

I try to add another record and got the same msg when I want to change that new record.

I know there is some SO posts about this kind of problem.
But all of them use custom pk or about file upload

Here is from admins.py

```
class MonitoringAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #list_filter = ('tebar',)
    list_display = ('tebar','food','foodqty','suplemen','suplqty','_weight','dead','wateradd','ph',)
    fields = ('tebar','food','foodqty','suplemen','suplqty','weight','dead','wateradd','ph',)
    def _weight(self,obj):
        return obj.xweight
    _weight.short_description = 'gr/ekor'


    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        try :
            if self.tebarObj.isrunning==True:
                return super(MonitoringAdmin,self).has_add_permission(request)
            return False
        except Exception as e :
            return False
    '''
    def has_change_permission(self, request):
        try :
            if self.tebarObj.isrunning==True:
                return super(MonitoringAdmin,self).has_change_permission(request)
            return False
        except Exception as e :
            return False
    '''

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        try :
            tebarId = dict(request.GET)['tebar__id__exact'][0]
            try :
                tebarObj = Tebar.objects.get(id=tebarId)
                assert tebarObj.kolam.user==request.user
                ret = qs.filter(tebar=tebarObj)
                self.tebarObj = tebarObj
                return ret
            except Exception as e:
                #print('LIST tebar__id__exact not owner')
                return Monitoring.objects.none()
        except Exception as e : # no tebar id
            #print('LIST no tebar__id__exact')
            return Monitoring.objects.none()
g

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        print('FFFK') 
        if db_field.name == 'tebar':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Tebar.objects.filter(kolam__user=request.user)
            try :
                filtertebar = dict(request.GET).get('_changelist_filters')[0]
                tebarId = int(filtertebar.split('=')[1])
                kwargs['queryset'] = kwargs['queryset'].filter(id=tebarId)
                kwargs['initial']=kwargs['queryset'].filter(id=tebarId)
            except Exception as e:
                kwargs['queryset']=Tebar.objects.none()

        if db_field.name in ['food','suplemen'] :
            bahanObjs = BahanServ.objects.filter(user=request.user)

            if db_field.name == 'food':
                kwargs['queryset'] = bahanObjs.filter(isfood=True)
            else :
                kwargs['queryset'] = bahanObjs.filter(isfood=False)

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Monitoring, MonitoringAdmin)
```

am I missing something?

Kindly please give me any solution (or clue) to fix this problem.

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Thankyou for your response. But I found it's caused by my stupidity, and I post my found below.

Answer (score 0):

Ah my stupidity ....

I didn't realize that the 'get_query_set' is also called when calling form.

So, I change the admin class to be:

```
class MonitoringAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #list_filter = ('tebar',)
    list_display = ('tebar','food','foodqty','suplemen','suplqty','_weight','dead','wateradd','ph',)
    fields = ('tebar','food','foodqty','suplemen','suplqty','weight','dead','wateradd','ph',)
    def _weight(self,obj):
        return obj.xweight

    _weight.short_description = 'gr/ekor'

    def has_module_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        try :
            if self.tebarObj[0].isrunning==True:
                return super(MonitoringAdmin,self).has_add_permission(request)
            return False
        except Exception as e :
            return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        try :
            if self.tebarObj[0].isrunning==True:
                return super(MonitoringAdmin,self).has_change_permission(request)
            return False
        except Exception as e :
            return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        try :
            if self.tebarObj[0].isrunning==True:
                return super(MonitoringAdmin,self).has_delete_permission(request)
            return False
        except Exception as e :
            return False

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(tebar__kolam__user=request.user)

        tebarFilter = None
        try :
            tebarFilter = dict(request.GET).get('_changelist_filters')[0]
            tebarFilter = tebarFilter.split('=')[1]
        except :
            try :
                tebarFilter =  dict(request.GET).get('tebar__id__exact')[0]
            except :
                try :
                    tebarFilter = request.session['tebarFilterId']
                except :
                    tebarFilter = None

        if tebarFilter is None :
            return Monitoring.objects.none()

        self.tebarObj = Tebar.objects.filter(id=int(tebarFilter))
        print("adding request.session['tebarFilterId']")
        request.session['tebarFilterId']=self.tebarObj[0].id

        return qs.filter(tebar=self.tebarObj[0])


    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'tebar':
            kwargs['queryset'] = self.tebarObj

        if db_field.name in ['food','suplemen'] :
            bahanObjs = BahanServ.objects.filter(user=request.user)

            if db_field.name == 'food':
                kwargs['queryset'] = bahanObjs.filter(isfood=True)
            else :
                kwargs['queryset'] = bahanObjs.filter(isfood=False)

        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Monitoring, MonitoringAdmin)
```

It fix my problem

Thanks all

-bino-